Does updating Ubuntu from v. 20.04 to 22.04 force reinstallation of Snap?
For various reasons*, I've completely removed Snap and snapd from Ubuntu 20.04, including adding the file, nosnap.pref, in /etc/apt/preferences.d/, to prevent reinstallation  of Snap and Snap-based packages. This has worked well when performing normal package updates, e.g., with sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade or the Synaptic package manager.
Would nosnap.pref be respected on upgrading to v. 22.04, or, after upgrading, must I repeat the process, removing all Snap packages and snapd, recreating nosnap.pref, and reinstalling the Debian packages from various PPA's that have been added, such as mozillateam/ppa?

* Some issues I've encountered with Snap:

Snap applications are slower to load.
Often, Snap applications are not kept updated. For example, Snap p7Zip and Snap IrfanView have not been updated for years. However, current Windows versions of IrfanView and 7-Zip work perfectly well under wine.
Snap installation files and space requirements are larger because they contain all dependencies.


You do know you can only release-upgrade from one LTS to the next LTS; ie. 20.04 to 22.04 LTS, which means there are multiple release-upgrade steps involved in going from 20.04 to 24.04 LTS !  and the requirements for release-upgrade are specific to each upgrade step (even if each 'releaseupgrade' document text is almost identical, as they're from created from a skeleton/standard, there are & can be difference in each).  Your question has you trying to implement a non-supported upgrade path.

This question is similar to: Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc, the question is not about the number of steps,  (i.e., 20.04 -> 22.04 -> 24.04), but about removing Snap. For that reason, I'll simplify it.

Each release-upgrade step is unique, with unique rules.  There has been some QA done on snapd removed systems, and some upgraded perfectly, whilst others would not!   It'll depend on a number of factors, including what product you're using (Server? Desktop? etc) PL:US what packages you have installed ... these details very & the packages are significant !   Many Ubuntu devs & members have blogged on how to disable snap, and it was these that were tested; then how snapd was disabled refined.. The results though were still specific to which release you were moving to.

The nosnap.pref you mention is a 3rd party addition, so ask the person who blogged about what you added. For what was tested, I'd have suggested trying what was actually blogged by Ubuntu devs directly as the QA was done using those steps. You opted for 3rd party blogger, so ask the third party blogged what tested they performed, OR work out what Ubuntu dev blog they based their document on & explore that & how close it was to what Ubuntu devs blogged & thus you can look at their testing/reports (20.04 to 22.04 upgrade QA was some years ago now too!)

In some cases, yes: Snap packaged may be reinstalled...

If there is a transitional deb that installs the snap, and...
That transitional deb has a higher version number than your non-Ubuntu deb, and...
You left snapd installed or allow it to be reinstalled.

Release-upgrade of a system without snapd (or pinned to prevent snapd from installing) may cause a different set of errors when you try to release-upgrade. It may prevent the release-upgrade from being successful.

As mentioned in the question, snapd, as well as the Snap packages have been uninstalled already, and it's reinstallation is forbidden by nosnap.pref. That is the reason for the question: would nosnap.pref be respected during upgrade process??

That's addressed by the third bullet. Your question doesn't specify what that file is or does. The instructions from that clickbait link might work...if you do them right, and if you don't override that apt-pin with some other customization.

So that seems like a definite "maybe". Perhaps that's the only answer, until I try it.

Executive Summary
The game is not worth the candle.
Explanation
There are various comments and answers that point to two possible issues:

Installation of a new version of Ubuntu might ignore the file in /etc/apt/preferences.d/ forbidding installation of package snapd.
Installation of a new version of Ubuntu might require snapd.

Ubuntu v. 20.04 LTS receives Expanded Security Maintenance (extra 5 years) until April 2030, using Ubuntu Pro, "Always free for personal use.", so there is no immediate security requirement to update Ubuntu itself. (Admittedly, there have been updates to the Linux kernel, not available on older versions of Ubuntu.)
Almost all software can be updated, and with quicker access to new versions, in most cases, than through Snap. So far, the one exception is Calibre, now built with a newer version of glibc, but the older Calibre version works well for my purposes.
Windows software steeped in wine can be updated, as is wine itself.
So there appears to be no need to go through multiple updates and removal of the unwanted package.: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

First bullet: Apt WILL obey the pinning file. The issue is that doing so may have other serious consequences during a release-upgrade. It's not a tested path.
